# Integrate SAML authentication within an exising website

Tags: php, saml

I am several days now trying to understand SAML and how to integrate in our web application to authenticate users.

I have been reading the following post:
http://www.gigya.com/blog/the-basics-of-saml/

(other references too, but it has been the most clear information I have read from a theory point of view)

I have installed simplesamlphp successfully, but I don't know how to use/configure to do the authentication from our website.

Also, I am trying to work with lightsaml, building the authn request, but honestly I don't know what I need to do more and the only thing I can get is the object created.

My colleagues have provided me the following information:

- ActiveLogOnUri
- DefaultInteractiveAuthenticationMethod
- FederationBrandName
- IssuerUri
- LogOffUri
- MetadataExchangeUri
- PassiveLogOnUri

I believe we have a valid sts ready to use with the information provided.

Our programming language is PHP, I would appreciate very much someone who may point to a practice guide and/or give me hints about what I will need to check/work with to have the need done.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't started I would recommend you to check OneLogin toolkit. I have used the php and ruby ones and they are very easy to setup and specially to test by creating a test Identity Provider in their website.  I don't work for them :).

https://developers.onelogin.com/saml/php

Comment: Hi, onelogin was one of the first resources I have found and initially I was very happy. But I skip it because the high costs. We will need to deal with about 1000 users. I have not started yet the integration ... I am exploring simplesamlphp and lightsaml. What do you think about those other solutions? Thanks!

Comment: OneLogin toolkits are open source and free. If your customers use OneLogin they will pay for the convenience of having the cloud SSO solution for their employees, but you still can legally use the toolkit without a cost for you.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your thoughts s1mpl3. I think what I am missing now is the IDP used in my auth request is not ready to accept request from my app (SP). I have contacted our IT department and I think they will need to take some action in the ADFS side. So, apparently my problem is not related to the library to use. I will take into account to give a try to onelogin toolkit once I am sure the ADFS side is ready. Thanks!